# Accessing in C# a method not defined in type library

Tags: c#

While creating a plugin for a third party application I hit a problem that the type library provided by the creators of the application does not contain all methods available for the plugins.

Basically everything works if I use *VisualBasic* and don't have the **Option Strict On** set. As soon as I set it to "On" I get errors that *Late binding is not available with Strict On*.

Now I really would like to port this code to C#, but I can't figure out how to get those methods to work.

The plugin system works in the way that my plugin gets an Application object and later I just call:
`Application.IntermediateObject.InterestingMethod(Variable)` - this works fine in VB without "Strict On"

In C# this doesn't even compile as **IntermediateObject** does not contain a definition of "InterestingMethod" (as I can also see by using the Windows SDK COM Object Browser).
My best guess so far was that I should be able to get to it with something like that:

```
IntermediateObject.GetType().GetMethod("InterestingMethod");
```

But the result of that is just "null".

Am I doing something wrong here? or is this a dead-end and I must stick to VB?

**PS**: I have no power to make the application creators fix their type library, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to employ the `dynamic` keyword here:

```
dynamic tmp = Application.IntermediateObject;
tmp.InterestingMethod(variable);
```

This might work, although I am not certain as reflection doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Downvoter: Leave a comment please. Otherwise I can't improve the answer. Thanks. As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Surely this was what `dynamic` was made for? Why the downvote?

Comment: @LorenzoDematté pretty much the *textbook* example

Comment: Actually, it is one of the reasons why dynamic was implemented... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714583.aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell exactly, this is why I upvoted and I am surprised by the downvotes too...Unless the OP is looking explicitly for a pre-C#4 solution

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I've had a look at the voting - nothing "obviously malicious" just from the data; at a guess, one person was simply mistaken, and another person believed them. I suspect you'll survive, given the net +3

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for looking. I didn't suspect the downvotes to be malicious - although I just received two more downvotes on other answers, also without a comment and also without the answer being obviously incorrect. I really don't care about the rep. I just feel a bit offended by anonymous downvotes if there is nothing obviously wrong, hence the comment.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, you do seem to have upset someone. Let me know if it continues.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks, I will, if it gets out of hand. I am not really worried about it, knowing that there are measures in place to prevent extensive abuse.

Comment: Thank you! The dynamic keyword did the trick. I must have overlooked it as the project was currently on .net 3.5 where it is not available, but there seems to be nothing stopping an upgrade to 4.0 so hopefully problem solved.